# How to access high-trust SharePoint 2013 add-in project services from another project like API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have created a high-trust SharePoint 2013 Add-in project to access my SharePoint server folders. 
It uses a self-signed certificate for the authentication purpose. My SharePoint server and SharePoint add-in, the project is running in the same machine.

My goal is to access the sharepoint add-in services from another project like API.

So I achieved this by adding a WebAPI NuGet packages to my sharepoint add-in project. I can successfully call the API methods in the add-in project. 
But the issue is when I try to call sharepoint context, HttpContext becomes null and it requires "Controller" instead of "ApiController". The code is as below

```
public class SPController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
            var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost();

            return new string[] { "Success" };
        }
    }
```

I searched a lot to find the solution but nothing works. 
How can I fix this issue? 
Is there any other workaround availabel to access the sharepoint add-in services from another project like API? If so, please share the links.